# PHP - inserting foreign key into the table giving error mysqli_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given on line 22

Tags: php, mysql

I got this error while inserting a foreign key constraint into the table.
I am new to php I don't know how to proceed.
here is my php code.

```
     <?PHP

    include_once('connection.php');
    /**
     * created by chandu on 24-03-2018 12:20 pm
     */
    $con=mysqli_connect($server_name,$user_name,$password,$db);

    if(!$con){
      die("Error Connection");
    }
     if(isset($_POST["workOrderName"]) && isset($_POST["submitted_on"]) && isset($_POST["status"]) && isset($_POST["subject"]) && isset($_POST["notes"])) {

       echo "**************************************";
       $status = $_POST["status"];
       $subject = $_POST["subject"];
       $notes = $_POST["notes"];
       $result = mysqli_query($con,"insert into ticket_raising(word_order_id,submitted_on,status,subject,notes) values('select word_order_id from workorder_category where workorder_name = 'workOrderName'',NOW(),'$status','$subject','$notes')");
       $isInserted = mysqli_num_rows($result);
       if ($isInserted>0) {
           # code...
           echo "Success";
       }
       else {
           echo "unsuccess";
       }
     }
     mysqli_close($con);
    ?>
```

Comment: whats mysqli_error say?

Comment: Don't quote the `select`, add the other values to it with commas. See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert-select.html. You also are open to SQL injections.

Comment: Also should be using http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.affected-rows.php

Comment: SQL INSERT statement syntax is wack.  `$result` is going to be FALSE (a boolean value), not a resultset. Also, [Little Bobby Tables](https://xkcd.com/327/) will tell you not to include potentially unsafe values in the text of a SQL statement ... https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SQL_Injection

Comment: @chris85 - what he said but just to elaborate `"insert into ... values('select .. where workorder_name = 'workOrderName'',NOW() ...)"`  so you have to remove the single quote at `'select` and the last one here `'workOrderName''`  This is causing some quote {block} issues which is probably causing a syntax error/warning maybe..  In any case this makes `$result` become boolean `false`, and hence the error you see.

Comment: @chris85 - kool {head tip}

Comment: Please share your table structure as well. I will then be able to assist better.

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/fjg9j.png and https://i.stack.imgur.com/vsRLh.png these are my table schemas @Hasnain Hayder

Answer (score 0):

The `select` is going to be inserted as a string, not executed as a SQL query with this execution (if you correct the quoting issue which currently is causing an invalid query). To use a [`insert select`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert-select.html) you should put all the values in the select. You also should parameterize the query. Passing values into a SQL query opens you to >a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection">SQL injections. So you query should be like this:

```
insert into ticket_raising(word_order_id,submitted_on,status,subject,notes) 
select word_order_id, NOW(), ?, ?, ? from workorder_category where workorder_name = ?
```

Then bind in the values you had, `$status`, `$subject`, `$notes`, and `workOrderName`.

You can read more about prepared statements with mysqli here: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php

A possible addition you could make to the table structure is making `submitted_on`'s default value the current_timestamp, then you won't need the `now()`.

Answer (score 0):

I think the subquery is returning many records which is not applicable to be fit into that column. Try doing this.

```
$result = mysqli_query($con,"insert into ticket_raising(word_order_id,submitted_on,status,subject,notes) values('select word_order_id from workorder_category where workorder_name = 'workOrderName' limit 1',NOW(),'$status','$subject','$notes')");
```

Also i noticed you are doing concatenation in wrong way try using concatenation operator to prevent errors.